# PHP loop foreach determine 2nd and 3rd iteration

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How can I detect 2nd and 3rd iteration

Here's what I did but It doesn't give the right answer

```
$sample_array = array('boom 1','boom 2','boom 3','boom 4','boom 5','boom 6','boom 7');

                            $separator2 = 0;
                            $separator3 = 0;
                            foreach($sample_array as $sample_array_value){
                                if(++$separator3 % 3 == 0)
                                {
                                    echo $sample_array_value."<br /><br /> Separator 3 <br /><br />";
                                }
                                else if(++$separator2 % 2 == 0)
                                {
                                    echo $sample_array_value."<br /><br /> Separator 2 <br /><br />";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo $sample_array_value."<br />";
                                }
                            }
```

**the output of that code is:**

```
boom 1
boom 2

Separator 2 

boom 3

Separator 3 

boom 4
boom 5

Separator 2 

boom 6

Separator 3 

boom 7
```

**Which is wrong, I need the output to be:**

```
boom 1
boom 2

Separator 2 

boom 3

Separator 3 

boom 4

Separator 2 

boom 5
boom 6

Separator 2 
Separator 3 

boom 7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need extra variables, since your array is 0-based indexed, you can just use the key. Also you have to change your logic a bit, so that you get your expected output, e.g.

```
foreach($sample_array as $key => $sample_array_value){

    echo $sample_array_value . "<br />";

    if(($key + 1) % 2 == 0 && ($key + 1) % 3 == 0)
        echo "<br>Separator 2 <br />Separator 3<br /><br />";
    elseif(($key + 1) % 2 == 0)
        echo "<br>Separator 2 <br /><br />";
    elseif(($key + 1) % 3 == 0)
        echo "<br>Separator 3 <br /><br />";

}
```

output:

```
boom 1
boom 2

Separator 2 

boom 3

Separator 3 

boom 4

Separator 2 

boom 5
boom 6

Separator 2 
Separator 3

boom 7
```

Comment: how can I use that without $key?, Cause in using mysql just like this foreach(mysql_fetch_array($query) as $get){}

Comment: @JoelEnanodJr Then initialize a variable before the foreach loop, e.g. `$count = 0;` and increment it at the end of the foreach loop, e.g. `$count++;`

Comment: Thank you sir @Rizier123, Even I don't Understand your code It solved my problem.. Im noob in loop hehe thanks much... by the way what's the meaning of e.g.?

Comment: @JoelEnanodJr You're welcome. (e.g. means something like: "for example")

Answer (score 0):

You're suppose to check for 2nd and 3rd outside the if that implements the boom. since you also want the separator to be done after the boom, then bring it down.

$sample_array = array('boom 1','boom 2','boom 3','boom 4','boom 5','boom 6','boom 7');

```
                        $separator2 = 0;
                        $separator3 = 0;
                        $count = 1;
                        foreach($sample_array as $sample_array_value){
                            echo $sample_array_value."<br />";
                            if($count % 3 == 0)
                            {
                                echo "Separator 3 <br />";
                            }
                            if($count % 2 == 0)
                            {
                                echo "Separator 2 <br /><br />";
                            }
                            $count++;

                        }
```